# SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list while reading csv file and alerting in js

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

Getting error: `missing ) after argument list` when reading csv file but when i am using to alert in javascript or assigning it to any variable in javascript.

```
<script>
    <% 
        String csv = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("c:/Testing.csv"));
            String text = "";
            while ((text = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                csv = csv + text;
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e) {}
    %>
    alert("<%= csv %>");
    var test = "<%= csv %>";
</script>
```

**OUTPUT:**

> Name,Party,Province,Age,Gender
>
> "Mourani, Maria",BlocQuebecois,Quebec,43,Female
>
> "Sellah, Djaouida",NDP,Quebec,30,Female
>
> "St-Denis, Lise",NDP,Quebec,72,Female
>
> "Fry, Hedy",Liberal,BritishColumbia,71,Female
>
> "Turmel, Nycole",NDP,Quebec,70,Female
>
> "Sgro, Judy",Liberal,Ontario,68,Female
>
> "Raynault, Francine",NDP,Quebec,67,Female
>
> "Davidson, Patricia",Conservative,Ontario,66,Female

Error:
[image: Error in firebug]

Page renders:

[image: render]

Comment: 1) always log exceptions 2) do not put script in JSP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is going to end up rendering like

```
alert(some text, 
some more text, 
and more);
var test = some text,
some more text,
and more;
```

Which is invalid for one the text is not wrapped in quotes. And even if you wrapped it in quotes javascript does not support multi-line strings (unless escaped at the end).

So you need to escape the backslash so the new line is preserved and then parsed in the js string. And wrap the output in quotes.

```
//...
csv = csv + text +"\\n";
//...
alert("<%= csv %>");
var test = "<%= csv %>";
```

Since your csv file also contains double quotes you can do one of two things

Wrap with single quotes

```
alert('<%= csv %>');
var test = '<%= csv %>';
```

But the csv file might also have single quote in it as well and will trigger the same error so the other thing to do is just escape the double quotes in the csv file before outputting it

```
<% csv.replace("\"","\\"");
alert("<%= csv %>");
var test = "<%= csv %>";
```

Comment: But aren't line breaks important in a cvs file?

Comment: Otherwise you don't know where a row ends. I mean, I guess you could the whole string on `,` in chunks of size 5...

Comment: That should fix it, just need to preserve the new line so it is used within the js string

Comment: i have done the way @patrick evans suggested but didn' work still the same

Comment: @Mayur, can you edit your question to show how you implemented it, and possibly the actual rendered source

Comment: @Mayur, also include what the rendered output looks like (view page source) and copy the script part

Comment: well thats a screen shot of the error and not the rendered page, but still it shows me what is wrong. Your csv file also contains quotes so they need to be escaped as well. I will edit my answer

Comment: i have also included what rendered page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57317/discussion-between-mayur-and-patrick-evans).

Comment: @patrick evans what to do if i encountered single quotes. how to replace it. if the file is "Raynault's, Francine",NDP,Quebec,67,Female

Comment: just like the others, do a simple string replace before outputting the csv